# How to write mathcal similar letters

Tags: math-mode, fonts, mathcal

In math mode, I want to achieve the following letters, which look similar to mathcal but aren't the same.

[image: POMDP Formulation]

Using mathcal generates the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \(\mathcal{(S, A, P, R, \Omega, O)}\)

\end{document}
```

[image: mathcal]

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz --  There's no Greek in `\mathcal`, but the definition doesn't check.  It just pulls in the symbol in the CM "Omega" slot in the font being used for `\mathcal`, which I think here is `msbm`.

Comment: You showed two images. The first image you included appears to be using the standard Computer Modern `\mathcal` (but `\Omega` is not in `\mathcal`). The second image you included appears to be either Mathematica Script Bold (mma) or the bold script from pxtx. If you'd like to try out different math fonts, [mathalpha](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) can help you with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to load any particular package.

[image]

Incidentally, `\mathcal{\Omega}` makes no sense at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{(S, A, O, P, Q, R)}$
\end{document}
```